# Prevent statusbar to be shown over NavigationView in devices with Notch

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I have an issue with my `NavigationView`, when it's expanded the statusBar is shown in semitransparent color over it and i would hide it completely by still keeping notch support.

It looks like this now:

[image]

I've tried to add

`android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` in my Activity but nothing chanded.

My styles.xml looks like this:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="primaryTextColor">#F4F4F6</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="secondaryTextColor">#96000000</item>
        <item name="recyclerViewTitleColor">#96000000</item>
        <item name="navColor">#2948ff</item>
        <item name="colorTurni">@color/blueLight</item>
        <item name="varianti">@color/green</item>
        <item name="blueDark">@color/blueDark</item>
        <item name="backgroundCardColor">#FFFF</item>
        <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.BottomSheetDialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">
            shortEdges
        </item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

What i would reach is this:

[image]

Activity.xml

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FAFAFA"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="it.gabtamagnini.visualposmobile.PtermActivity">


    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    ...

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_menu"
        android:layout_width="185dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_header">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/layout_menu"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="5dp" />

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps but take a quick look at this: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec

Comment: Sorry, couldn't reproduce it; you'd pls share something that allows to reproduce it.

Comment: @Zain i've added the activity xml code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cause:

This shadow is related to the drawable used for the inset foreground which is customized to [`R.styleable.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout_insetForeground`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/a577676/design/src/android/support/design/internal/ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.java#57) style by default on the `NavigationView`; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28858631/9851608) explains more about the `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout` class.

### Solution:

Getting rid of this drawable from the `NavigationView` either programmatically or in layout:

**Programmatically:** setting [`setScrimInsetForeground`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/navigation/NavigationView#setScrimInsetForeground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) to null.

```
navView.setScrimInsetForeground(null)
```

**In layout:** using `app:insetForeground="@null"`:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_menu"
    ....
    app:insetForeground="@null"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your `NavigationView` not in `activity`

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

it will solve your issue

Comment: added  it to NavigationView but nothing changed.